# PHP Directory rewrite rules

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've the following structure for my MVC php application.

```
/

/Models/
/Views/
/Content/
/libs/

index.php    <-- Controllers
admin.php
blog.php
```

Basically I want people to allow acces .php files in the root directory. (index.php, admin.php)

For example allow only acces to index.php

```
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

For some strange reason people can acces URL's like index.php/index.php/index.php

or blog.php/test/ it will display the output page but it doesn't render properly.

Why is this happaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Basically I want people to allow acces .php files in the root directory. (index.php, admin.php)`

Instead of `<Files>` directive use `mod_rewrite` for finer control:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|admin)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Ok this for whitelisting allowed php files but people are still able to go to index.php/{anything here} or admin.php/{anythinghere} or even index.php//////

Comment: It doesn't matter they will still be running the code on index.php or admin.php there are no security issues. If you are worried about people actually doing this and it rendering incorrectly use absolute paths in your html.

Comment: Or if you are really worried about it use a redirect instead of a rewrite if they aren't at one of the whitelisted files.

Comment: There must be some sort of rewrite rule to : 

site.com/index.php{Deny everything inserted here including forward slashes} if you get what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Try updated code now, it will block anything after `/index.php` now.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> For some strange reason people can acces URL's like index.php/index.php/index.php

It's not a BUG, it's a FEATURE ;)

This is actually an apache feature. Apache allow addtional path information after the script name. In php you can acesss this value from $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
The URL index.php/a/b will run the script index.php and you will get "a/b" in PATH_INFO

> How to disable this type of URL

To disable such url you need to disable "AcceptPathInfo" in apache configuration

```
<Files "*.php">
  AcceptPathInfo Off
</Files>
```

You can find more about AcceptPathInfo in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Answer (score 0):

`/index.php/index.php/index.php` isn't a valid path. The root `/index.php` is still the one that is being run by the server. However the browser isn't smart enough to know this so if you paths to css and image files are relative it is now looking for them in the wrong places that is why your page isn't rendering properly.

So as far as the server is concerned `www.test.com/index.php/index.php/index.php` is the same as calling `www.test.com/index.php`

But for the browser if you had this in your html header `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` it is now trying to find it in  `www.test.com/index.php/index.php/css/style.css` and of course it doesn't exist there.

Comment: Ok so what would be the solution? I want anything after http://site/*.php/ to be redirected to http://site/index.php

Comment: Use mod_rewrite as anubhava has suggested.